# Personalizar WCFM Marketplace

Tags: php, woocommerce

Tengo el siguiente codigo que actualmente funciona en woocommerce .

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values_2', 10, 3);
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values_2($_product, $item, $item_id = null) {
$order_id = get_the_ID();
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$value = wc_price( $order->get_subtotal() + $order->get_shipping_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );
if($item['type']=="line_item"){
echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $order->get_total_tax() . '</td>';
```

Me gustaria implementarlo dentro de WCFM Marketplace. Y no se como se puede usarlo para ese formulario. La tabla es woocommerce_order_items